# TypeScript: remove key from type/subtraction type

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript, decorator, higher-order-components

I want to define a generic type `ExcludeCart<T>` that is essentially `T` but with a given key (in my case, `cart`) removed. So, for instance, `ExcludeCart<{foo: number, bar: string, cart: number}>` would be `{foo: number, bar: string}`. Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

Here's why I want to do this, in case I'm barking up the wrong tree: I'm converting an existing JavaScript codebase to TypeScript, which contains a decorator function called `cartify` that takes a React component class `Inner` and returns another component class `Wrapper`.

`Inner` should take a `cart` prop, and zero or more other props. `Wrapper` accepts a `cartClient` prop (which is used to generate the `cart` prop to pass to `Inner`), and any prop that `Inner` accepts, *except* `cart`.

In other words, once I can figure out how to define `ExcludeCart`, I want to do this with it:

```
function cartify<P extends {cart: any}>(Inner: ComponentClass<P>) : ComponentClass<ExcludeCart<P> & {cartClient: any}>
```

Comment: Not yet, but there's a suggestion  - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183. See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While there isn't a built-in subtraction type, you can currently hack it in:

```
type Sub0<
    O extends string,
    D extends string,
> = {[K in O]: (Record<D, never> & Record<string, K>)[K]}

type Sub<
    O extends string,
    D extends string,
    // issue 16018
    Foo extends Sub0<O, D> = Sub0<O, D>
> = Foo[O]

type Omit<
    O,
    D extends string,
    // issue 16018
    Foo extends Sub0<keyof O, D> = Sub0<keyof O, D>
> = Pick<O, Foo[keyof O]>
```

In the question's case, you would do:

```
type ExcludeCart<T> = Omit<T, 'cart'>
```

With TypeScript >= 2.6, you can simplify it to:

```
/**
 * for literal unions
 * @example Sub<'Y' | 'X', 'X'> // === 'Y'
 */
export type Sub<
    O extends string,
    D extends string
    > = {[K in O]: (Record<D, never> & Record<string, K>)[K]}[O]

/**
 * Remove the keys represented by the string union type D from the object type O.
 *
 * @example Omit<{a: number, b: string}, 'a'> // === {b: string}
 * @example Omit<{a: number, b: string}, keyof {a: number}> // === {b: string}
 */
export type Omit<O, D extends string> = Pick<O, Sub<keyof O, D>>
```

[test it on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20for%20literal%20unions%0D%0A%20*%20%40example%20Sub%3C'Y'%20%7C%20'X'%2C%20'X'%3E%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Y'%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Sub%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%20extends%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20D%20extends%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%20%3D%20%7B%5BK%20in%20O%5D%3A%20(Record%3CD%2C%20never%3E%20%26%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20K%3E)%5BK%5D%7D%5BO%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20Sub%3C'Y'%20%7C%20'X'%2C%20'X'%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Remove%20the%20keys%20represented%20by%20the%20string%20union%20type%20D%20from%20the%20object%20type%20O.%0D%0A%20*%0D%0A%20*%20%40example%20Omit%3C%7Ba%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string%7D%2C%20'a'%3E%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%20%7Bb%3A%20string%7D%0D%0A%20*%20%40example%20Omit%3C%7Ba%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string%7D%2C%20keyof%20%7Ba%3A%20number%7D%3E%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%20%7Bb%3A%20string%7D%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Omit%3CO%2C%20D%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CO%2C%20Sub%3Ckeyof%20O%2C%20D%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20X%20%3D%20Omit%3C%7Ba%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string%7D%2C%20keyof%20%7Ba%3A%20number%7D%3E)

Comment: This is great, thanks! All of the previous implementations of `Omit` that I'd tried didn't work on generics, but these ones do.

Comment: Very cool! Adrian, did you develop this, or did you find it somewhere else? If it's from somewhere else, can you link to that source? I was trying to look into your answer to see if it had any limitations or any other relevant discussion about it. I've also linked to your answer from mine because it seems to work well

Comment: @JKillian no, I can't remember where I got it from, but various variants are discussed on the corresponding TS issue, for example https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458

Comment: I remember going through that exact thread and trying all the variants there around the time I posted this question, and all of the ones I tried didn't work for generics (as in, you could go `Omit<T, 'foo'>` where `T` was some concrete type, but something like `function myfunc<T extends {foo: any}>(in: T) : Omit<T, 'foo'>` would break with rather confusing errors). So I'm not sure if it's a different way of defining `Omit` that popped up later or an improvement/bugfix in TS, but I think your answer was correct at the time it was posted, @JKillian :)

Answer (score 88):

**Update for TypeScript 3.5**: The [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type is now available. Please see [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512834/5023438) for an example usage.

---

**Old Answer**: Since [TypeScript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) and the introduction of [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu), It's now possible to write this as follows:

```
type Without<T, K> = {
    [L in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[L]
};
```

Or alternatively, and more concisely, as:

```
type Without<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

For your usage, you could now write the following:

```
type ExcludeCart<T> = Without<T, "cart">;
```

Comment: This works pretty good. One thing I noticed was that if `T` has types that are optional, after using `Without` they are all required. Do you know why that is?

Comment: The docs also mention that `type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` will also work, [in the 2.8 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) (down the bottom of the linked section). This version of `Omit` seems to work as expected with optional members too.

Comment: This is a good answer, I couldn't figure out how to scale it to multiple keys. [I took an attempt at a more direct use of exclude in another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242538/20774) That approach scales rather easily.

Answer (score 75):

While this has been correctly answered, I wanted to point out that [TypeScript 3.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html) did add an [`Omit<T, E>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) type.

```
type NoCart = Omit<{foo: string, bar: string, cart: number}, "cart">;
```

This results in the `{foo: string, bar: string}` type.

Comment: To omit multiple, do `type NoCart = Omit<{foo: string, bar: string, cart: number}, "cart" | "bar">;`

Comment: Omit seems easier

Answer (score 2):

there is another very simple way to have this result

When combining type in typescript, the type "never" have higher priority to everything.

You can simply create a type:

```js
type noCart<T> = T & {cart : never}
```

Or, without creating type

```
function removeCart<T>(obj : T) : T & {cart : never} {
    if("cart" in obj) {
        delete (obj as T & {cart : any}).cart;
    }
    return <T & {cart : never}> obj;
}
```

This is less generic than the solution of Adrian, but a bit simpler when we don't need the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Update: See [Adrian's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47643102/3124288) for a solution to this question. I've left my answer here though since it still contains some useful links.

---

There are various old requests for this feature (["outersection" types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6895), [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183)), but none have really progressed.

Recently, with the addition of mapped types I asked about this again, and Anders said that [while there's no plans to make a general subtraction type operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114#issuecomment-259472327), a more limited version might be implemented, presumably looking something like [this proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215).

I've personally run into quite similar situations to you when working with React, and unfortunately haven't been able to find any good solution. In a simple case, you can get away with something like:

```
interface BaseProps {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
}

interface Inner extends BaseProps {
    cart: Cart;
}

interface Wrapper extends BaseProps {
    cartClient: Client;
}
```

but I almost find this to be a semantic abuse of the `extends` keyword. And of course, if you don't control the typings of `Inner` or `BaseProps`, then this won't work out.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately I can't really do what you're suggesting, because I want to be able to just type `MyComponent = cartify(MyComponent)` (or `@cartify↵class MyComponent…` once that syntax lands) and have TypeScript automatically infer the correct type for the wrapped component. And it's a reusable library, so I definitely can't predict `Inner` ahead of time either.

Answer (score 1):

Probably all the answers are correct, but I built a shorter `Subtract` generic which does what you need:

```
type Subtract<T extends K, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, for instance, ExcludeCart<{foo: number, bar: string, cart: number}> would be {foo: number, bar: string}

You can use the [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) syntax to do this directly:

```
Exclude<{foo: number, bar: string, cart: number}, { cart: number}>
```

Comment: I believe simply `Exclude<{ foo: number, bar: string, cart: number }, "cart">` will do the trick.

Comment: You're right! I was thinking `Omit<{foo: number, bar: string, card: number}, "cart">` which achieves the correct result. Again. thanks for double checking! Should I delete the comment above?

Comment: Oh neat. I will have to try that out. Up to you on the comment.