# How can I abstract passing repeated children properties while keeping types non-optional?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that gets used multiple times in succession with some identical properties and some unique properties:

```
interface InsideComponentProps {
    repeatedThing: string;
    uniqueThing: string;
}

const InsideComponent: React.SFC<InsideComponentProps> = ({ repeatedThing, uniqueThing }) => (
    <div>{repeatedThing} - {uniqueThing}</div>
);

const Example = () => (
    <div>
        <InsideComponent repeatedThing="foo" uniqueThing="1" />
        <InsideComponent repeatedThing="foo" uniqueThing="2" />
        <InsideComponent repeatedThing="foo" uniqueThing="3" />
    </div>
);
```

The duplicate `repeatedThing` properties bother me, so I'm seeking a way to remove that redundancy. One thing I've done in non-TypeScript applications is to introduce a wrapper component that clones all of the children, adding the repeated properties in the process:

```
interface OutsideComponentProps {
    repeatedThing: string;
}

const OutsideComponent: React.SFC<OutsideComponentProps> = ({ repeatedThing, children }) => (
    <div>
        {React.Children.map(children, (c: React.ReactElement<any>) => (
            React.cloneElement(c, { repeatedThing })
        ))}
    </div>
);

const Example = () => (
    <OutsideComponent repeatedThing="foo">
        <InsideComponent uniqueThing="1" />
        <InsideComponent uniqueThing="2" />
        <InsideComponent uniqueThing="3" />
    </OutsideComponent>
);
```

The resulting JavaScript code has the behavior I want, but the TypeScript compiler has errors because I'm not passing all of the required properties when I instantiate `InsideComponent`:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:27:26
    TS2322: Type '{ uniqueThing: "1"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InsideComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{ uniqueThing: "1"; }' is not assignable to type 'InsideComponentProps'.
    Property 'repeatedThing' is missing in type '{ uniqueThing: "1"; }'.
```

The only solution I've thought of is to mark `InsideComponent`s `repeatedThing` property as optional, but that's not ideal because the value *is* required.

How can I preserve the strictness of making sure that `InsideComponent` does actually receive all of the props while reducing the duplication of the properties at the call site?

I'm using React 16.2.0 and TypeScript 2.6.2.

Comment: Note that specifying callback argument types, while not the cause here, can both create awkward type errors and hide real bugs. `map(components, (c: React.ReactElement<any>) => ...)` should be `map, components, c => ...)`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I gathered that from [How to assign the correct typing to React.cloneElement when giving properties to children?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42261783/155423); are you saying the answer is incorrect?

Comment: No, I am not saying that answer is incorrect. He is using a type assertion `c as ReactElement<any>`, which is good style when necessary, as in that answer. You are hiding the type assertion behind a `(c: ReactElement<any>) =>`. This is bad style because, you are actually using an assertion `as`, but we only know that by reading the definition of `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript checks to make sure that you assign all required properties to the React element. Since you assign the extra properties in the `OutsideComponent` the compiler can't really check that.

One option would be to specify children as a function that takes extra properties as a parameter and spread them to `InsideComponent`. The syntax is a bit more convoluted but it is more type safe:

```
interface OutsideComponentProps {
    repeatedThing: string;
    children: (outerProps: OutsideComponentProps) => React.ReactElement<any>;
}

const OutsideComponent: React.SFC<OutsideComponentProps> = (o) => o.children(o);

const Example = () => (
    <OutsideComponent repeatedThing="foo">{(o) => 
        <div>
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="1" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="2" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="3" {...o} />
        </div>
    }</OutsideComponent>
);
```

> It seems that `OutsideComponent` is very abstract and thus reusable; is there any way to convert it into a very generic component that takes all of its props and provides them as the argument, without having to define an `OutsideComponentProps` for each case?

While you can use generic functions as components, you can't specify type parameters explicitly, they can only be inferred. This is a drawback, but ultimately it can be worked around.

```
function GenericOutsideComponent<T>(props: { children: (o: T) => React.ReactElement<any> } & Partial<T>, context?: any): React.ReactElement<any> {
    return props.children(props as any);
}

const Example = () => (
    <GenericOutsideComponent repeatedThing="foo">{(o: InsideComponentProps) =>
        <div>
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="1" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="2" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="3" {...o} />
        </div>
    }</GenericOutsideComponent>
);
```

Similar to your original JavaScript solution, there is the risk that some required properties of `InsideComponent` are not specified as the properties of  `GenericOutsideComponent` are `Partial<T>` (to allow only `repeatedThing` to be specified) and `o` is `T` because otherwise the compiler will consider `repeatedThing` is not specified and will require it on `InsideComponent`. If setting a dummy value on `InsideComponent` is not a problem, just change the signature of `children` to `(o: Partial<T>) => React.ReactElement<any>` but this is less then ideal.

Another option is to be explicit about which properties are on `GenericOutsideComponent` using a `Pick`:

```
function GenericOutsideComponent<T>(props: { children: (o: T) => React.ReactElement<any> } & T, context?: any): React.ReactElement<any> {
    return props.children(props);
}

const Example = () => (
    <GenericOutsideComponent repeatedThing="foo">{(o: Pick<InsideComponentProps, "repeatedThing">) =>
        <div>
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="1" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="2" {...o} />
            <InsideComponent uniqueThing="3" {...o} />
        </div>
    }</GenericOutsideComponent>
);
```

Comment: I had not thought about using a function for `children`! It seems that `OutsideComponent` is very abstract and thus reusable; is there any way to convert it into a very generic component that takes all of its props and provides them as the argument, without having to define an `OutsideComponentProps` for each case?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think I figured out a workable generic solution, have a look. The bounty was definitely a motivator :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to TypeScript, but this may be an alternative:

```
// OutsideComponent.tsx
import * as React from "react";

const OutsideComponent: React.SFC<{ children?: React.ReactNode, [rest: string]: any }> = (props) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {React.Children.map(children, ((child, i) =>
                React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>, { key: i, ...rest }))
            )}
        </div>
    )
};

type Sub<
    O extends string,
    D extends string
    > = {[K in O]: (Record<D, never> & Record<string, K>)[K]}[O]

export type Omit<O, D extends keyof O> = Pick<O, Sub<keyof O, D>>

export default OutsideComponent;
```

(`Omit` type taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47643102/3208258))

Then

```
import OutsideComponent, { Omit } from './OutsideComponent';

const Example = (): React.ReactElement<any> => {
    const PartialInsideComponent: React.SFC<Omit<InsideComponentProps, 'repeatedThing'>> = InsideComponent;

    return (
        <OutsideComponent repeatedThing="foo">
            <PartialInsideComponent uniqueThing="1" />
            <PartialInsideComponent uniqueThing="2" />
            <PartialInsideComponent uniqueThing="3" />
        </OutsideComponent>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a full solution that does what is wanted, while still providing type safety and code hints using the VSCode setup I have.

**Partialize.tsx**

```
import React, { cloneElement } from "react";

/**
 * This HOC takes a `Component` and makes some of it's props optional as defined by `partialProps`
 *
 * @param Component The component to make some props optional
 * @param partialProps The properties to make partial
 */
export const withPartialProps = <
  TProps extends {},
  TKeys extends (keyof TProps)[]
>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>,
  partialProps: TKeys
) => {
  type TPartialProps = typeof partialProps[number];

  return (
    props: Omit<TProps, TPartialProps> & Partial<Pick<TProps, TPartialProps>>
  ) => {
    partialProps.forEach((propName) => {
      if (props[propName] === undefined) {
        throw Error(`${propName} is undefined`);
      }
    });

    return <Component {...(props as TProps)} />;
  };
};

/**
 * This HOC takes a `Component` and returns two components, the partial version created by `withPartialProps`,
 * and a wrapper component that will provide the now optional props to the child elements;
 *
 * @param Component The component to partialize
 * @param partialProps The properties to make partial
 *
 * @see withPartialProps
 */
export const partialize = <TProps extends {}, TKeys extends (keyof TProps)[]>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>,
  partialProps: TKeys
) => {
  type TPartialProps = typeof partialProps[number];
  type TChildProps = Omit<TProps, TPartialProps> &
    Partial<Pick<TProps, TPartialProps>>;
  type TWrapperProps = Pick<TProps, TPartialProps> & {
    children:
      | React.ReactElement<TChildProps>[]
      | React.ReactElement<TChildProps>;
  };

  return {
    Partial: withPartialProps(Component, partialProps),
    PartialWrapper: ({ children, ...props }: TWrapperProps) => (
      <>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
          cloneElement(child, props as any)
        )}
      </>
    )
  };
};
```

**Demo.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { partialize } from "./Partialize";

type FooProps = {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z: "a" | "b" | "c";
};

const Foo = ({ x, y, z }: FooProps) => (
  <p>
    x: {x} | y: {y} | z: {z}
  </p>
);

export const Bar = partialize(Foo, ["y"]);
export const Baz = partialize(Foo, ["z"]);
```

**Example usage**

```
<Baz.PartialWrapper z="b">
  <Baz.Partial x={1} y="Text #1" />
  <Baz.Partial x={2} y="Text #2" />
</Baz.PartialWrapper>
```

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sun-1d3xb)

The end result is some rather messy types, but should fulfill the needs of the question.